# Need help to convert some keys from a tuple dictionary in another dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a csv file that I read with csv module in a csv.DictReader().
I have an output like this:

```
{'biweek': '1', 'year': '1906', 'loc': 'BALTIMORE', 'cases': 'NA', 'pop': '526822.1365'}
{'biweek': '2', 'year': '1906', 'loc': 'BALTIMORE', 'cases': 'NA', 'pop': '526995.246'}
{'biweek': '3', 'year': '1906', 'loc': 'BALTIMORE', 'cases': 'NA', 'pop': '527170.1981'}
{'biweek': '4', 'year': '1906', 'loc': 'BALTIMORE', 'cases': 'NA', 'pop': '527347.0136'}
```

And I need to get the 'loc' as key for a new dict and the count of the 'loc' as values for that new dict, as the 'loc' have a lot of repetitions in the file.

```
with open('Dalziel2015_data.csv') as fh:
    new_dct = {}
    cities = set()
    cnt = 0
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh)
    for row in reader:
        data = dict(row)
        cities.add(data.get('loc'))
        for (k, v) in data.items():
            if data['loc'] in cities:
                cnt += 1
                new_dct[data['loc']] = cnt + 1
    print(new_dct)
```

example_file:

```
biweek,year,loc,cases,pop
1,1906,BALTIMORE,NA,526822.1365
2,1906,BALTIMORE,NA,526995.246
3,1906,BALTIMORE,NA,527170.1981
4,1906,BALTIMORE,NA,527347.0136
5,1906,BALTIMORE,NA,527525.7134
6,1906,BALTIMORE,NA,527706.3183
4,1906,BOSTON,NA,630880.6579
5,1906,BOSTON,NA,631295.9457
6,1906,BOSTON,NA,631710.8403
7,1906,BOSTON,NA,632125.3403
8,1906,BOSTON,NA,632539.4442
9,1906,BOSTON,NA,632953.1503
10,1907,BRIDGEPORT,NA,91790.75578
11,1907,BRIDGEPORT,NA,91926.14732
12,1907,BRIDGEPORT,NA,92061.90153
13,1907,BRIDGEPORT,NA,92198.01976
14,1907,BRIDGEPORT,NA,92334.50335
15,1907,BRIDGEPORT,NA,92471.35364
17,1908,BUFFALO,NA,413661.413
18,1908,BUFFALO,NA,413934.7646
19,1908,BUFFALO,NA,414208.4097
20,1908,BUFFALO,NA,414482.3523
21,1908,BUFFALO,NA,414756.5963
22,1908,BUFFALO,NA,415031.1456
23,1908,BUFFALO,NA,415306.0041
24,1908,BUFFALO,NA,415581.1758
25,1908,BUFFALO,NA,415856.6646
6,1935,CLEVELAND,615,890247.9867
7,1935,CLEVELAND,954,890107.9192
8,1935,CLEVELAND,965,889967.7823
9,1935,CLEVELAND,872,889827.5956
10,1935,CLEVELAND,814,889687.3781
11,1935,CLEVELAND,717,889547.1492
12,1935,CLEVELAND,770,889406.9283
13,1935,CLEVELAND,558,889266.7346
```

I have done this. I got the keys alright, but I didn't get the count right. 
My results:

```
{'BALTIMORE': 29, 'BOSTON': 59, 'BRIDGEPORT': 89, 'BUFFALO': 134, 'CLEVELAND': 174}
```

I know pandas is a very good tool but I need the code with csv module.
If any of you guys could help me to get the count done I appreciate.
Thank you!
Paulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count occurrences of the cities in CSV file. `Counter.keys()` will also give you all cities found in CSV:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('csvtest.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh)
    c = Counter(row['loc'] for row in reader)
    print(dict(c))
    print('Cities={}'.format([*c.keys()]))
```

Prints:

```
{'BALTIMORE': 6, 'BOSTON': 6, 'BRIDGEPORT': 6, 'BUFFALO': 9, 'CLEVELAND': 8}
Cities=['BALTIMORE', 'BOSTON', 'BRIDGEPORT', 'BUFFALO', 'CLEVELAND']
```

Comment: Hey @Andrej Kesely You have the job done. Totally forgot about Counter. Great tool. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating a global counter and not the counter for the specific location. You are also iterating each column of each row and updating it for no reason.

Try this:

```
with open('Dalziel2015_data.csv') as fh:
    new_dct = {}
    cities = set()
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh)
    for row in reader:
        data = dict(row)
        new_dct[data['loc']] = new_dct.get(data['loc'], 0) + 1
    print(new_dct)
```

This line: `new_dct[data['loc']] = new_dct.get(data['loc'], 0) + 1` will get the last counter for that city and increment the number by one. If the counter does not exist yet, the function `get` will return 0.

Comment: Hi @Klaus It didnt work. Give the same results I got. Maybe I messed up some line in between 8(. But thank you for your time.

Comment: See now if it works. Also please remember to always post the expected output in your answer.

Comment: Hi Klaus. Thanks again and now it worked to. Sorry but as a did put the example file I thought that the numbers of times in the ex was enough to see the expected results. My bad. Thank you